# From a list of datetime timestamps across multiple days, how to find the last time stamp across each day?

Tags: python, datetime

Apologize if this is a very basic question. Thanks much for your time to go over this.

I have CSV data in the following format.

```
2019-05-10 13:00:00 some_data,some_more_data,...
2019-05-10 16:20:10 some_data,some_more_data,...
2019-05-10 19:21:10 some_data,some_more_data,...

2019-05-11 01:10:10 some_data,some_more_data,...
2019-05-11 12:24:10 some_data,some_more_data,...

2019-05-12 01:10:10 some_data,some_more_data,...
2019-05-12 12:24:10 some_data,some_more_data,...
2019-05-12 23:10:10 some_data,some_more_data,...
2019-05-12 12:24:10 some_data,some_more_data,...
```

From the above listed data, how can one filter out the data corresponding to the last timestamp in a given day ?

I have employed some string parsing and achieved the following result - but am looking to find an efficient way / alternatives.

So, the desired output will be.

```
2019-05-10 19:21:10 some_data,some_more_data,...
2019-05-11 12:24:10 some_data,some_more_data,...
2019-05-12 23:10:10 some_data,some_more_data,...
```

Tried some really ugly string splitting - and datetime comparision.

```py
monday_morning_report_data = 'C:\\Users\\a071927\\Dropbox\\monday_morning_report\\monday_morning_report_data\\test.csv'


# Open CSV file in to read data from it.
open_report_file_to_read = open(monday_morning_report_data, 'r', newline='')
monday_morning_report_generation = csv.reader(open_report_file_to_read)


# Create an empty list which will gather a list of all dates only - %Y-%m-%d
list_of_all_dates = list()

# From each row of the csv file, which is a list with ONE string.
for each_timestamp_info in monday_morning_report_generation:
    # Split the string into a list.
    time_stamp_all_data = each_timestamp_info[0].split(',')
    # From the split list, get the index 0 which is the complete timestamp.
    time_stamp_info_date_time_str = time_stamp_all_data[0]
    # gather only %Y-%m-%d by splitting at ' '
    time_stamp_info_date_time_str_date_only = time_stamp_info_date_time_str.split(' ')[0]
    # if that day is not in list_of_all_dates append it.
    if time_stamp_info_date_time_str_date_only not in list_of_all_dates:
        list_of_all_dates.append(time_stamp_info_date_time_str_date_only)


# now list_of_all_Dates has the list of all unique days.
for each_day in list_of_all_dates:
    open_report_file_to_read = open(monday_morning_report_data, 'r', newline='')
    monday_morning_report_generation = csv.reader(open_report_file_to_read)

    #Gather TIMES within each unique day.
    list_of_times_in_the_given_day = list()
    # From each row of the csv file, which is a list with ONE string.
    for each_timestamp_info in monday_morning_report_generation:
        # Split the string into a list.
        time_stamp_all_data = each_timestamp_info[0].split(',')
        # From the split list, get the index 0 which is the complete timestamp.
        time_stamp_info_date_time_str = time_stamp_all_data[0]
        # gather only %Y-%m-%d by splitting at ' ' - index 0
        time_stamp_info_date_time_str_date_only = time_stamp_info_date_time_str.split(' ')[0]
        # gather only '%H:%M:%S' splitting at ' ' - index 1
        time_stamp_info_date_time_str_time_only = time_stamp_info_date_time_str.split(' ')[1]
        if each_day == time_stamp_info_date_time_str_date_only:
            list_of_times_in_the_given_day.append(time_stamp_info_date_time_str_time_only)
            #print(time_stamp_info_date_time_str_time_only)

    # initialize a max timestamp default of 00:00:00
    max_time_stamp_within_a_day = datetime.strptime('00:00:00', '%H:%M:%S')
    # initialize string with ' ' - this will be populated later.
    max_time_stamp_within_a_day_str = ''

    #Now from the list of unique times within a given day.
    for each_time in list_of_times_in_the_given_day:
        if datetime.strptime(each_time,'%H:%M:%S') >= max_time_stamp_within_a_day:
            # update the max time - date time value
            max_time_stamp_within_a_day = datetime.strptime(each_time,'%H:%M:%S')
            # update the string.
            max_time_stamp_within_a_day_str = each_time

    # once the max time / last time within a day is calculated.
    final_timestamp = each_day + ' ' + max_time_stamp_within_a_day_str

    # Print given unique day.
    print(each_day)
    # print list of times data was gathered during this day
    print(list_of_times_in_the_given_day)
    # print the final and latest timestamp.
    print(final_timestamp)

    open_report_file_to_read = open(monday_morning_report_data, 'r', newline='')
    monday_morning_report_generation = csv.reader(open_report_file_to_read)


    for each_timestamp_info in monday_morning_report_generation:
        time_stamp_all_data = each_timestamp_info[0].split(',')
        time_stamp_info_date_time_str = time_stamp_all_data[0]
        # From the final timestamp get the data.
        if time_stamp_info_date_time_str == final_timestamp:
            print(each_timestamp_info)
    print('---------')

open_report_file_to_read.close()
```

IS there any efficient way to achieve the same ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `pandas`. One thing to note is that your csv data does not have a comma between the dates and `some_data`. I pre-processed the data to split those. Also note that the solution below will only work if the data is sorted by date. If it is not sorted, you can add a `df.sort_index()` after the `set_index` call below.

```
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.parser import parse

df = pd.read_csv('path_to_csv.csv')
df.iloc[:,0] = df.iloc[:,0].apply(parse)
df.set_index(df.columns[0], inplace=True)
indices = df.index.floor('D')
new_df = df[~indices.duplicated(keep='last') | ~indices.duplicated(keep=False)]
```

Essentially, what we are doing here is parsing the date column as datetime objects and then setting that as the index of the DataFrame. Then we are getting those indices, floored to their `Day`. That essentially creates a `Series` of dates, which we can then de-duplicate and keep the position of last value from each set of duplicates.